# if statement for Highcharts xAxis labels

Tags: jquery, if-statement, highcharts

I have managed to get this if statement to run the first part, but it will not run the else if bit correctly. I must be placing something incorrectly because it only shows (Not Designated) on the xAxis. Wondering why the else if part is not working.

```
labels: {
    formatter: function() {
        // custom formatter
        if (this.x == null) { return "(Not Designated)";

        } else if (this.x != null ) {

            return this.x;
        }                      
},
```

It must have something to do with how I am getting the data then, because my original if statement was like this...

```
if (this.x == null) return '(Not Designated)';

else return this.x;
```

If I use the "===" setup it does not show the (not designated) or any xAxis values, if I use the "==" it will show the (not designated) for all xAxis items. I understand that it is a really simple function to do this, but its not working and it either has something to do with Highcharts formatter or the data I am trying to gather. I have not dealt with null values much either so sorry for the bad markup examples...thanks for the comments!

Comment: try using "===" for equality match. you can also code this in one line like "return this.x || '(Not Desginated)';"

Comment: I tried that after looking at some other threads, just tried it again and it shows no xAxis values with the "===" equal to setup. Thanks for the one line example, will help me out for sure. Very odd because the tooltip has the same basic formatter piece and it works fine.

Comment: I second @Sumit 's comment. But to address the initial set up - why would you bother with an if else anyway? You're checking whether 'this.x' *is* something with your if statement - you don't need to then check if 'this.x' is *not* that same thing, you could just use an 'else'. Which is basically what the one line solution is shorthand for.

Comment: is it possible that you should be comparing against `undefined` rather than `null`?

Comment: Anything is possible at this point, I will have to show this to our main programmer because I think it has to do with the actual database itself. I will post my solution once it is finalized, thanks again.

Comment: can you provide the whole function please, If it returns `"(Not Designated)"`. That's mean that this.x is null. You can set a breakpoint there and see by yourself

Comment: Here is a [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/uxdeveloperkr/th0x3h8k/) of something similar, I am working on a test server that is not accessible on stack overflow so this will have to do.

Comment: In the fiddle you provided,  you forgot to encapsulate formatter into labels{}.
It's working pretty good with `this.value`, instead of `this.x`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When I check this.x using debugger it looks like undefined:
[image]

I replace "this.x" by "this.value", the chart is working.
Here is the [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/mushigh/vjxq8fcn/).

```
  if (this.value == 0) {
    return '(Not Designated)';

  } else if (this.value != 0) {

    return this.value;
  }
```

It will be great if you can share the categories that you are using!

Comment: That worked for the xAxis, I now have this under control for both the data labels (my answer below) and the xAxis labels. I can post a link to the live charts when I am finished.

Answer (score 1):

First of all, in the fiddle you gave, the formatter function wasn't encapsulated into labels property.

```
labels: {
            formatter: function() {

         if (this.value == 0) {return '(Not Designated)';}
         else {return this.value;}
        },
        },
        },
```

There were also 2 other problems:

1. `this.x` is undefined, so checking with `===` won't show the x-axis because this operator will check if values are strictly equals (more info [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/523643/difference-between-and-in-javascript)). since undefined is undefined, you can't check for its value.
2. When you have null into a category name, highcharts will replace it with its index, so that's why even with `==` it wasn't working.

I suggest to replace the `null` by a `0` and the `this.x` by `this.value`.
Here's your working [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/yvbenitah/th0x3h8k/3/).

Comment: I ended up changing to the dataLabels because I couldn't get the other stuff to work. I guess more understanding of how the data comes across is helpful eh, thanks for helping a newbie with bad examples!


I was so confused about the null values coming back as numbers, now I understand why that is happening. Seems so simple now.

Answer (score 0):

Here is what I ended up with in the end, took me a while but glad that this handles all null values and all blank values, in case any of you have a similar issue with your database.

```
// format the xAxis labels to handle null and blank values from database
 formatter: function() {
   if (this.x === null) {
   return "(Not Designated)" + '<br>' + '$' + Highcharts.numberFormat(this.y, 0);
    } else if (this.x === '') {
      return "(Not Designated)" + '<br>' + '$' + Highcharts.numberFormat(this.y, 0);
 }
   return this.x + ' ' + '$' + Highcharts.numberFormat(this.y, 0);
}
```

Comment: [Here](http://www.followthemoney.org/entity-details?eid=16039) is the finished column chart. Now, if I could only get the dang thing to actually be responsive that would be nice but maybe not possible with a non responsive site...